# How can I export CSV file from json with the result of multiplication via JQ

Tags: json, terminal, jq

I have json something like this

```
{"lastUpdateId":18891938,
"bids":[
    ["3.23600000","101.76600000"],
    ["3.23500000","2161.63600000"],
    ["3.23100000","30.95000000"],
    ["3.23000000","3.12600000"],
    ["3.22900000","303.95100000"]
],
"asks":[
    ["3.24100000","15.90200000"],
    ["3.24200000","1679.00000000"],
    ["3.24500000","953.98800000"],
    ["3.24800000","7.57700000"],
    ["3.25400000","37.26700000"]
]}
```

Then I would like to export it to CSV with the result of multiplication for every rows(i.e. 1st row should be something like this)

> "bids","3.23600000","101.76600000","329.314776" <- this is calculated from 3.23600000 * 101.76600000

now, the code below export 1st numbers and 2nd number but the result of their multiplication.

```
jq -r keys[] as $k | select(.[$k]|type=="array") |[$k]+.[$k][]|@csv
```

How can I export the result of multiplication together in the end of each line?

https://jqplay.org/s/8zMbHxlfoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need add one line to the jq program:

```
keys[] as $k 
| select(.[$k]|type=="array") 
| [$k]+.[$k][]
| .[length]= (.[-2:]|map(tonumber)|.[0]*.[1])
|@csv
```

You might wish to throw in a `tostring`.