# How can I add calculated values to exported csv when using JQ?

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq, reduce

I have json data just like this below

```
{"lastUpdateId":18891938,
"bids":[
    ["1","50"],
    ["2","40"],
    ["3","30"],
    ["4","20"],
    ["5","10"]
],
"asks":[
    ["6","10"],
    ["7","20"],
    ["8","30"],
    ["9","40"],
    ["10","50"]
]}
```

Then the code below can export the result of CSV just like this

```
jq -r keys[] as $k  | select(.[$k]|type=="array")  | [$k]+.[$k][] | .[length]= (.[-2:]|map(tonumber)|.[0]*.[1]) |@csv
```

Result:

```
"asks","6","10",60
"asks","7","20",140
"asks","8","30",240
"asks","9","40",360
"asks","10","50",500
"bids","1","50",50
"bids","2","40",80
"bids","3","30",90
"bids","4","20",80
"bids","5","10",50
```

what if I want another columns for the minimum value of all asks(Here, it's 6)?,
the sums for each asks and bid, and the ratio against the sums for each asks and bids?

So I'd like to have the CSV result something like this(4-6th columns are the new that I want)

```
asks,6,10,60,6,1300,0.046153846
asks,7,20,140,6,1300,0.107692308
asks,8,30,240,6,1300,0.184615385
asks,9,40,360,6,1300,0.276923077
asks,10,50,500,6,1300,0.384615385
bids,1,50,50,6,350,0.142857143
bids,2,40,80,6,350,0.228571429
bids,3,30,90,6,350,0.257142857
bids,4,20,80,6,350,0.228571429
bids,5,10,50,6,350,0.142857143

6 is minimum value for asks. 1300 is total sum for asks(60,140,240,360,500), 350 is total sum for bids(50,80,90,80,50), and the last values for each line is ratio(4th col/6th col)
```

https://jqplay.org/s/2Qsdopx8A4

Comment: Given your previous questions in this series (most recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67137631/how-can-i-export-csv-file-from-json-with-the-result-of-multiplication-via-jq), permit me to suggest that since SO is not a free coding service, it would be a good idea if you showed that you were making some effort to solve your problem by showing what you have tried beyond the previously posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, a helper function:

```
def mul: (.[0]|tonumber) * (.[1]|tonumber);
```

Next, we can adapt the solution you mentioned by first computing the minimum of the "ask" values:

```
  ([.asks[][] | tonumber] | min) as $min
  | keys[] as $k 
  | select(.[$k]|type=="array")
  | ([.[$k][] | mul] | add) as $sum
  | [$k]+.[$k][] 
  | (.[-2:]|mul) as $c4
  | . + [$c4, $min, $sum, $c4 / $sum]
  | @csv
```

To eliminate the quotation marks for numeric values, you could use `tonumber`.  To eliminate all the quotation marks, you could replace the call to `@csv` by a call to `join(",")`, but then the results are not guaranteed to be the CSV you expect.